# Change attr base on select input

Tags: jquery, html, paypal

I'm using a CMS for event's, this CMS doesn't support multiple payment choices so I manage to made some modifications to the core, I have added a few new classes, controllers, helpers, and model's, so that I can add multiple payment choices, I did this because last time I asked how to make modifications to a CMS you all told that instead of changing the core I should add new classes or controllers as needed that way the security risks will be minimum, so that's what I did...

anyway, the multiple payment system is "working" with a minor flaw...
The user has to select 2 main options

1 is to select the monthly percentage
and the other is for selecting the payment method such as, PayPal, eWay, Google Checkout, Payza and so on...

so each payment has a different rate sort of speak... but in this case, they monthly payments rate and the payment method both has the same rate...

So I was wondering that instead of clicking in two similar options why not just click in one option and pass the value to the other option without the need to click again...

I have simplified the HTML code for better understanding

```
<div class="hides">
    <p class="title">This area is not visible in a live site<p><br>
<input type="radio" checked="checked" name="eb_PagosMensuales" value="Un Solo Pago (0%)" class="inputbox flush">Un Solo Pago (0%)
<br>
<input type="radio" name="eb_PagosMensuales" value="3 Meses (+4.55%)" class="inputbox flush">3 Meses (+4.55%)
<br>
<input type="radio" name="eb_PagosMensuales" value="6 Meses (+7.25%)" class="inputbox flush">6 Meses (+7.25%)
<br>
<input type="radio" name="eb_PagosMensuales" value="9 Meses (+11.25%)" class="inputbox flush">9 Meses (+11.25%)
<br>
<input type="radio" name="eb_PagosMensuales" value="12 Meses (+13.50%)" class="inputbox flush">12 Meses (+13.50%)
<br>
</div>

<hr />

<div>
<input type="radio" checked="checked" value="os_paypal" name="payment_method" onclick="changePaymentMethod();">Paypal 0% Intereses <br>
<input type="radio" value="os_paypal3" name="payment_method" onclick="changePaymentMethod();">Paypal a 3 Meses con 4.55% de Interes <br>
<input type="radio" value="os_paypal4" name="payment_method" onclick="changePaymentMethod();">PayPal a 6 Meses con 7.25% de Interes <br>
<input type="radio" value="os_paypal5" name="payment_method" onclick="changePaymentMethod();">Paypal a 9 Meses con 11.25% de Interes <br>
<input type="radio" value="os_paypal6" name="payment_method" onclick="changePaymentMethod();">Paypal a 12 Meses con 13.50% de Interes <br>
</div>
```

If user select

PayPal 3, then the input radio button with the value "3 Meses (+4.55%)" will be selected automatic

if user select

PayPal 6, then the input radio button with value "6 Meses (+7.25%)" will be selectec automatic

and so on...

This is the query that I'm trying to use... I'm aware that is not finish, I'm thinking that if this few lines work then the rest will be simple, but is not working and I'm getting bald for pulling my hair...

```
$('input[name*=payment_method]').live('change', function() {

 if ( $('input[name*=os_paypal]').is(':checked')) {
      $('input[name*=eb_PagosMensuales')[0].setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
     alert("PayPal 1 has been selected...");
 }

/*    else { 
   $('#some_other_id_that_i_migh_need').removeAttr('required');
    }
    */
});
```

the idea is to select 1 option from the second group of radio buttons and by doing so one of the first group of radio buttons will be selected accordingly to the data on the second group.

Please take a look in a more visual example here:
[Link to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k4Y4z/18/)

Thank you for taking the time to read my question, I appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var $ebs = $('input[name="eb_PagosMensuales"]');
var $paymethods = $('input[name=payment_method]').on('change', function() {
    var idx = $paymethods.index(this);
    $ebs.eq(idx).prop('checked', true)
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qQhNS/)